# Make text display on canvas in real-time during input

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want the user to input text outside of a canvas element and have it display on the canvas in real-time or when a button is pressed.

I'm very new to canvas and JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried? Did you get stuck somewhere? Please remember Stack Overflow is not a code writing service! We expect some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple pattern. 
You can learn more about text in canvas here: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp

```js
/* Very basic canvas setup */
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

      /* Function what is called on every input change */
      var UserInput = document.getElementById("UserInput");
      UserInput.oninput = function() {
        // Sending to console text which is now in input
        //console.log(UserInput.value);

        /* Drawing text taken from input on 100, 100 */
        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(UserInput.value, 100, 100);

      };
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>


    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="250" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>

    <input type = "text" id = "UserInput">

 

  </body>
</html>
```